# Is Scala faster than Java 7 for number crunching and for heavy string processing?

Tags: scala, java-7

Assume there are two class of applications:

(1) Intensive number crunching and numerical and mathematical computations

(2) Intensive string regex expression matching, xpath searching, and other string manipulations where strings are mostly stored in collection classes.

In Both cases assume clients access these applications thousands of times per second or even in parallel.

So if I have the choice to implement the applications in the server backends, I can choose either Java 7 or Scala. Which one should I choose to get faster performance and produce more reliable code?

Comment: Unless someone has done objective comparisons between these languages on precisely these tasks, you'll be likely to get subjective answers here.

Comment: Why should scala be faster? (They both run on the JVM so when you have differences they will probably be small)

Comment: The only way I can see Scala is faster, is in case Scala uses better datastructures.

Comment: Scala can use specialization, which removes the need to box/unbox primitives when using generic datastructures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google did some benchmarks recently that you might find interesting - see paper linked to here: http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/06/cpp-go-java-scala-performance-benchmark.php

The paper is surprisingly un-scientific, but you will get a rough feel for what can be done. Of particular interest may be section V.F

> Daniel Mahler improved the Scala version by creating a
>   more functional version, which is kept in the Scala Pro
>   directories. This version is only 270 lines of code, about 25%
>   of the C++ version, and not only is it shorter, run-time also
>   improved by about 3x. It should be noted that this version
>   performs algorithmic improvements as well, and is therefore
>   not directly comparable to the other Pro versions.

It's not clear to me whether this version with algorithmic improvements is included in their speed benchmark table (I don't think so), but it does indicate that you may be able to produce performance improvements by adopting algorithmic improvements that are more viable to implement in Scala. It won't do much for simple string processing, however.

A big factor will be how competent you are in programming these languages, and how good you are at optimizing them. Java is obviously more verbose but you're less likely to run into performance "gotchas".

Answer (score 2):

Two points which might enable better performance for numerical computations than in Java:

- The practical one: Scala makes it extremely easy to enable parallel computation of "embarrassingly parallel" problems. While the same could be done in Java it would require much more time and expertise, making it likely that it will only be done in rare circumstances.
- The technical one: Scala can specialize generic data structures for primitive types, making boxing/unboxing unnecessary. The Java compiler is not able to do that.

Scala uses Java's String so the amount of possible improvements here is quite limited. But there are other data structures like ropes which provide better performance than String in some cases.

Comment: Another factor speculated elsewhere is that Scala emphasizes by default immutable objects. As such, it vastly simplifies the work the GC has to do to evaluate "liveness" of object instances. Combine the super easy parallel computation with significantly reduced GC cycles and it doesn't take much for a Scala implementation to shoot right past Java in being higher performance.

Comment: Unfortunately specialization doesn't work very well (yet) in practice because there are so few things specialized in the standard Scala library.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your expertise and effort, I would expect that you can get better results here or there. Normally, with an infinite amount of development time and money, you can improve, improve and improve your code in every language. (Think of bigger and bigger caches, specialised sorters, precomputed defaults and so on).

With a good understanding of both languages and some experience in performance questions of your field, I wouldn't expect much differences, but you could save some time by the more collection friendly scala approach, and the time, saved on normal development, could be spend in performance analysis and improvement.

Answer (score 1):

There is in principle not really a reason why Scala would be faster than Java for number crunching applications.

I would not choose Java or Scala or any other JVM language if I wanted to write a serious high-performance number crunching application.

From my own [experience](https://github.com/jesperdj/scalaray) (and ofcourse this is only anecdotal evidence and definitely not proof that this is true in all cases) the JVM is not the best suited platform for heavy number crunching. If raw number crunching speed is important you would probably be better off with something that's more close to the "metal", for example C++, which allows you to for example use Intel SSE instructions and do other low-level optimizations, or use the GPU with [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) if your algorithm is suitable for that.